# Que tipo de dados (double, float ou decimal) eu deveria usar para representar moeda em .NET com C#?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem

Embora eu tenha noção do que seria melhor utilizar, faço esta pergunta para fins didáticos já que vejo diversos exemplos de pessoas usando `double` em C#. Porém já tive problemas com `double` para cálculos com moeda e li em diversos lugares que o tipo perde precisão em alguns casos.

Portanto, em que situações seria melhor utilizar cada tipo?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

O `Decimal` é o tipo ideal para cálculo de valores. Tem uma amplitude enorme (79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 até -79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335) e possui uma das menores margens de erro para arredondamento.

`Double` é mais adequado para cálculos científicos gerais, onde a margem de erro não é desprezível, mas é tolerável. Apesar de ter um intervalo de valores maior, o cálculo da mantissa e da característica produz problemas conhecidos de arredondamento.

`Float` é um `Double` com menos bytes para representação, portanto, com uma amplitude de valores pequena e os problemas de precisão e arredondamento semelhantes ao `Double`.

Answer (score 14):

O mais indicado é `decimal`, [segundo o próprio MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/364x0z75.aspx):

> Comparado aos tipos de ponto flutuante, o tipo decimal tem **mais precisão** e um **intervalo pequeno**, o que torna apropriado para cálculos financeiros e monetários.

Ele tem precisão de 28-29 dígitos, o bastante para não afetar os centavos com cálculos.

O `double` tem 15-16, e o `float` somente 7 dígitos de precisão.

---

A observação é que se não for feito cálculos precisos no sistema, *poderia* ser usado `float` já que ele ocupa somente 32-bits (contra 128 do decimal). Mas na prática isso não representa um problema a não ser que você irá ter um grande array de decimais, por exemplo.

Nesse caso, você deve determinar se importa mais uma boa prática de uso de espaço ou a consistência de todas as variáveis monetárias estarem tipadas como `decimal` em seu código (boa prática de programação).

Comment: A precisão do tipo decimal é 28-29 dígitos significativos.

Answer (score 4):

O tipo [`Decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) realmente é o tipo adequado para valor monetário e outros valores que exijam exatidão de valores. Inclusive o literal deste tipo é a letra `M` no final do número para indicar que deseja que seja um número especificamente deste tipo, justamente de *money*.

Note que, ao contrário do que diz as outras respostas, ele tem mais exatidão, e não precisão (ele tem mais precisão também, mas para valor monetário ele é irrelevante, se não for usar Bitcoin até um `float` tem precisão suficiente, mas não exatidão). Precisão demais atrapalha, mas o tipo decimal permite você controlar isso, o que é muito importante também, você pode limitar a precisão dele, ao contrário de `float` e `double`.

[Entenda os termos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/516306/101). Esses tipos de ponto flutuante binário não podem representar todos os números possíveis, mas não exatamente por amplitude, porque ele é amplo, mas ele não é tão granular, ou seja, ele pula alguns números, portanto ele consegue chegar perto do que você está querendo, mas não exatamente em muitos casos.

[Eu expliquei melhor isso em outra resposta e não vou repetir aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Ao contrário do que diz a resposta aceita, ele não tem menores margens para arredondamento, ele não tem arredondamento indesejado. E ele tem maiores arredondamentos justamente porque ele troca a precisão pela exatidão. Mas aí são arredondamentos desejados, pelo menos dentro da matemática que conhecemos. E de fato, com dinheiro, é comum trabalharmos com menos precisão, ou seja, com duas casas depois da vírgula apenas (pode ser outra quantidade, Bitcoin usa 8, Yen usa 0, Real (BRL) pode usar até 4 de acordo com a legislação, em certas situações), ou seja, arredonda mais que um `float` ou `double`, de propósito, algo que estes últimos não permitem com exatidão.

Em qualquer tipo, arredondamentos desejáveis são necessários, alguns mais que outros. Em dinheiro, no uso mais normal, se você dividir 10 por 3, você terá 1 centavo sobrando que terá que decidir onde colocar.

Quem usa `float` ou mesmo `double` que tem mais precisão, mas ainda não exatidão, e disfarça mais o erro de arredondamento indesejado, está cometendo grave erro, principalmente para fins didáticos, porque ela está ensinando o erro. E se você treinar o erro é ele que você fará, por isso até banco tem programador que comete este tipo de erro (em JavaScript que não tem um tipo decimal nativo e tem que pegar uma biblioteca ou cuidar na mão o tempo todo para que o arredondamento indesejado não aconteça, ou a falta dele).

Nem sempre documentação usa os termos corretamente, muitas vezes quem escreve não entende do assunto, mas o objetivo dela é ensinar usar o mecanismo correto e não terminologia geral.

Pra trabalhar com dinheiro o ideal mesmo seria usar um tipo feito só para isto, mas dá para trabalhar sem e quase todo mundo trabalha. Existem bibliotecas diversas por toda a internet com algum [tipo `Money`](https://github.com/search?q=c%23%20money). Eu vi algumas delas há algum tempo atrás e não gostei de nenhuma, mesmo que muitas resolvam o principal problema. Quem sabe um dia eu crie uma. Pode ser útil também o uso de um `Currency`, especialmente em aplicações que usam várias moedas diferentes, e algumas dessas bibliotecas já citadas tem o tipo também. Não me responsabilizo por nenhuma.

Isso não é questão de boa prática e não faz o menor sentido economizar o espaço deixando de lado a exatidão quando se fala em dinheiro, isso dá prejuízo ou lucro extra que pode render até processo judicial. Ou faz certo ou faz errado, boa prática é algo opcional, isto não é.

Claro que o tipo certo é o mais importante, mas entender e usar os termos corretos demonstram mais profissionalismo e compromisso com a ciência. Isso molda seu cérebro. Em um trabalho na área de exatas, até mesmo em ciências humanas e biológicas, é importante falar certo, explicar o correto, mesmo que o errado funcione igual porque o mecanismo é o mesmo. Quem tem apreço pela ciência é chato mesmo ;)