# Qual o mais recomendável "try" ou "if"

Tags: c#, .net, if, conversão-de-tipo, try-catch

```
{   
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double SalarioBase = 0, Descontos = 0, Vantagens = 0;
        try
        {
            SalarioBase = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
            Vantagens = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            Descontos = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Valores Invalidos");
            return;
        }
        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString (( SalarioBase + Vantagens ) - Descontos);
    }
}
```

Qual a diferença entre usar o `if` e o `try`

Comment: As duas respostas respondem bem a pergunta sobre `if` e `try..catch`, mas recomendo perguntar sobre arquitetura de software - tem tag especifica aqui no SO. No exemplo da sua pergunta a inteligência da sua aplicação está na "tela" ou *view*, e isso não é uma boa prática.

Answer (score 21):

> Qual a diferença entre usar o if e o try

Bom, são bem diferentes entre si. `if` serve para fazer um fluxo condicional. `try ... catch` serve para pegar erros (ou exceções, no linguajar correto) e dar a esses erros o tratamento adequado.

Por exemplo, em seu código:

```
try 
{
    SalarioBase = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
    Vantagens = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
    Descontos = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
}
catch
{
    MessageBox("Valores inválidos");
    return;
}
```

Se houver um erro de conversão em qualquer um dos três campos, seu código irá para o `catch`, ou seja, imprimirá uma mensagem de erro e sairá da função.

Sobre o título da sua pergunta:

> Qual o mais recomendável try ou if

Não existe isso de "mais recomendável" neste caso. Cada um serve a um propósito diferente, tanto que podem ser usados juntos. Por exemplo:

```
try 
{
    if (!Double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out SalarioBase))
    {
        MessageBox("Salário não está no formato correto.");
    }

    if (!Double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out Vantagens))
    {
        MessageBox("Vantagens não está no formato correto.");
    }

    if (!Double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out Descontos))
    {
        MessageBox("Descontos não está no formato correto.");
    }
}
catch
{
    MessageBox("Ocorreu algum erro não previsto.");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Eu não usaria nenhum dos dois, ou até usaria o `if`, mas de uma forma diferente:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var textBox1 = "123.45"; //só para facilitar o teste
        var textBox2 = "10"; //só para facilitar o teste
        var textBox3 = "abc"; //só para facilitar o teste
        double SalarioBase;
        if (!double.TryParse(textBox1, out SalarioBase)) WriteLine("Salario Base foi digitado incorrentamente");
        double Vantagens;
        if (!double.TryParse(textBox2, out Vantagens)) WriteLine("Vantagens foi digitado incorrentamente");
        double Descontos;
        if (!double.TryParse(textBox3, out Descontos)) WriteLine("Descontos foi digitado incorrentamente");
        WriteLine(SalarioBase);
        WriteLine(Vantagens);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZkEEPD). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hAcxu6). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/Texto2Double.cs).

Pra mim exceções [só devem ser usadas em situações excepcionais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56299/101) (inclusive porque [é lenta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17632/101)), o que não é o caso. Números digitados podem estar errados e é bem normal que a conversão não seja possível. Então prefiro o [`TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Double__).

Alguém pode alegar que o `try-catch` pode resolver todos de uma vez só, só que normalmente não é o desejado, em geral para cada um precisa de um tratamento diferente. Uma função poderia simplificar esses casos.

Se estiver usando C# 7 pode simplificar cada bloco:

```
//note que não precisa declarar a variável aqui, ela fica disponível no escopo
if (!double.TryParse(textBox1, out var SalarioBase)) { 
    WriteLine("Salario Base foi digitado incorrentamente");
}
```

Outro detalhe importante é [não usar `double` para valor monetário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38140/101), [prefira `decimal`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11340/101) que funciona corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você já espera por um erro, sempre utilizo o **If**, pois gera um código mais limpo.

Caso contrário, opte pelo **try catch**

Comment: Não sei porque tantos votos negativos. É simples: IF se o erro é esperado no fluxo do programa, caso contrário é uma exceção e deve ser usado o TRY/CATCH. O SOpt pune a objetividade e quem é conciso, e é inóspito pra iniciantes, que não entenderam ainda que aqui foge às regras de QA.