# Erro de conversão de tipo ao salvar no banco de dados

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, ado.net

Meu projeto tem um formulário `frmAdicionarProduto` para adicionar produtos ao banco de dados contendo seguintes `TextBox` e `ComboBox`:

```
txtProduto  
txtQuantidade  
cmbTipo  
txtValorFornecedor  
txtValorFinal  
txtLucro
```

Estou tendo problemas para salvar valores abaixo de 1 inteiro.

Tenho problemas apenas com números abaixo de 1, acima de 1 pode ser número inteiro ou decimal que não tenho problemas.

**Exemplo 1:** 0,99 = Erro
**Exemplo 2:** 1,57 = Sucesso

**Obtendo valor do lucro**

```
private void txtValorFinal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double lucro; // Criação da variável que ira comportar o valor do lucro
    lucro = Convert.ToDouble(txtValorFinal.Text) - Convert.ToDouble(txtValorFornecedor.Text); // Cálculo do lucro e comportando o valor na variável lucro
    txtLucro.Text = lucro.ToString("0.00"); // Populando o TextBox txtLucro com o valor da variável lucro
}
```

**Adicionando os dados no banco de dados**

```
string strConn = "Data Source=DESKTOP-AJLR3DB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBGestor;Integrated Security=True";
Ado insert = new Ado(strConn);
insert.InsertProduto(txtNomeProduto.Text,
    Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantidade.Text),
    cmbTipo.Text,
    Convert.ToDouble(txtValorFornecedor.Text),
    Convert.ToDouble(txtValorFinal.Text),
    Convert.ToDouble(txtLucro.Text));
MessageBox.Show("Produto cadastrado com sucesso!", "Sucesso!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
this.Close();
this.Dispose();
```

**Ado.cs**

```
string ConectionString;

public void InsertProduto(string nomeProduto, int quantidade, string tipo, double valorFornecedor, double valorFinal, double lucro)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConectionString);
    string cmdString = "INSERT INTO produtos VALUES ('" + nomeProduto.ToString() +
        "', '" + quantidade +
        "', '" + tipo.ToString() +
        "', '" + valorFornecedor +
        "', '" + valorFinal +
        "', '" + lucro + "')";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex; // Essa linha é setada com o erro descrito no fim da pergunta
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Ao clicar no botão para adicionar os dados, está me retornando o seguinte erro:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Erro ao converter tipo de dados varchar em numeric.'

**OBS:** Deixei alguns comentários nos códigos para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Veja se isso não da te ajuda [Que tipo de dados (double, float ou decimal) eu deveria usar para representar moeda em .NET com C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11340/que-tipo-de-dados-double-float-ou-decimal-eu-deveria-usar-para-representar-mo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O jeito correto de converter é assim:

```
private void txtValorFinal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (decimal.TryParse(txtValorFinal.Text, out var valorFinal) && decimal.TryParse(txtValorFornecedor.Text, out var valorFornecedor)) {
        txtLucro.Text = (valorFinal - valorFornecedor).ToString("0.00");
    } else {
        //tratar o erro aqui
    }
}

//essa classe Ado parece desnecessária ou mal formulada
var insert = new Ado("Data Source=DESKTOP-AJLR3DB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBGestor;Integrated Security=True");
insert.InsertProduto(txtNomeProduto.Text,
    //tem que fazer o mesmo do acima,
    cmbTipo.Text,
    //tem que fazer o mesmo do acima,
    //tem que fazer o mesmo do acima,
    //tem que fazer o mesmo do acima);
MessageBox.Show("Produto cadastrado com sucesso!", "Sucesso!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    //e se der erro?
this.Close(); //duvido que isto está correto aqui
this.Dispose(); //quase certo que não deveria estar aqui
```

Assim:

```
//o mais certo é receber um objeto com estas propriedades e não esse monte de parâmetro
public void InsertProduto(string nomeProduto, int quantidade, string tipo, decimal valorFornecedor, decimal valorFinal, decimal lucro) {
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConectionString)) {
        conn.Open();
        //não sei o nome das colunas no banco de dados chuetei o que deveria ser
        var cmString = "INSERT INTO produtos (Nome, Quantidade, Tipo, ValorFornecedor, ValorFinal, Lucro) VALUES (@Nome, @Quantidade, @Tipo, @ValorFornecedor, @ValorFinal, @Lucro";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", nomeProduto);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantidade", quantidade);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", tipo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorFornecedor", valorFornecedor);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ValorFinal", valorFinal);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lucro", lucro);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/InsertProduct.cs).

Veja [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

E procure sobre [SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100730/101).

Então há alguns erros no código:

- Está convertendo de forma que gera erro, tem que verificar se deu certo.
- Está usando ponto flutuante binário para valor monetário, precisa ser decimal.
- Está Tratando exceção, e de um jeito bastante errado (tem pleo menos 3 erros só na exceção) quando o correto é usar `using`.
- Está permitindo SQL Injection quando deveria parametrizar a *query*.
- Está abusando de parâmetros quando deveria usar um objeto
- Está dispondo de algo em lugar errado.
- Provavelmente o campo `Lucro` não deveria existir no banco de dados porque é informação duplicada, mas depende do contexto para ter certeza.

Por sorte deu erro em uma situação. Não pode confiar no que funciona, é preciso estar certo.

Isto funciona, mas está certo?:

[image: Fiat 147 todo bagaçado andando pelas ruas]

Comment: Tenho que colocar `if` em todas as conversões aonde você colocou o comentário `//tem que fazer o mesmo do acima,`?

Comment: Sim, deve verificar se a conversão deu certo, se não deu não pode prosseguir.

Comment: Estou quase desistindo kkkkkk Depois de todos os erros setados por você.