# Tratamento de Exceção não funciona

Tags: c#, winforms

Quando insiro letra no txtIdade, o programa deveria retornar a mensagem de exceção. 
Mas não retorna, o Visual Studio informa que há exceção sem tratamento.

```
try
{
    var conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["strConexao"]);
    var comm = new OracleCommand($"insert into Nome(nome,idade,endereco) values ('{txtNome.Text}','{txtIdade.Text}','{txtEndereco.Text}')", conn);

    conn.Open();
    var reader = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    read();

}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "erro");
    return; 
}
```

Comment: Faça do jeito correto (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/293843/101) e não terá esse problema. Pode até ter outro, mas não esse. Este código é absolutamente inseguro.

Comment: Deve ser porque está acontecendo outro erro, experimente colocar apenas Exception para ver qual erro vai disparar, pois ele é o pai de todos os exceptions.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas! Alterei e dei certo aqui! Nem tinha noção que estava inseguro, estou no começo ainda..

Comment: @ViníciusMalon Então publique uma resposta com as alterações que você fez e que solucionaram o seu problema.