# Tem como converter um array de strings para um array de double sem que os números decimais informados sejam concatenados na conversão?

Tags: c#, array, conversão-de-tipo, conversão

Eu gostaria que, de alguma forma, após a conversão do array de string para double, os valores permanecessem com ponto flutuante. Eu coloco a entrada como, por exemplo, 5.5 6.5 7.8 2.5 6.2, e durante a conversão não é levado em conta que são números com casa decimal, eles são concatenados e vira 55, 65, 78, 25 e 62.

Já tentei fazer a conversão de várias formas. Meu objetivo final era acumular os valores somados em uma variável.

```
string[] notas = new string[5];
Console.WriteLine("Informe 5 notas: ");
notas = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

for (int i = 0; i < entradas.Length; i++)
{
  soma += Convert.ToDouble(entradas[i]); // a soma da errado pq considera os números concatenados
}
```

```
string[] notas = new string[5];
Console.WriteLine("Informe 5 notas: ");
notas = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

double[] vetor = notas.Select(Convert.ToDouble).ToArray(); // double[] vetor = Array.ConvertAll(notas, Convert.ToDouble);

for (int i = 0; i < notas.Length; i++)
{
  soma += vetor[i]; // a soma da errado pq considera os números concatenados, não com o ponto flutuante
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `Convert.ToDouble` considera a cultura, como você não informou uma cultura como parâmetro será usada a configurada globalmente (no sistema operacional ou alguma configuração global pra aplicação ou pra VM). Provavelmente você está com a cultura em português (onde o separador de decimal é virgula) e está inserindo a entrada usando ponto como separador (ou vice-versa).

Se o tratamento de cultura não importa muito pra você (ao que parece é uma aplicação para fins de estudos) é possível usar `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` e considerar o ponto como o divisor de decimais.

Isso vai funcionar pra ambos os códigos postados.

```cs
string[] notas = new string[5];
Console.WriteLine("Informe 5 notas: ");
notas = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

double soma = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < notas.Length; i++)
{
    soma += Convert.ToDouble(notas[i], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
}

Console.WriteLine(soma);
```

Note que o melhor tipo de dados para armazenar notas é `decimal` e não `double`. Você pode ver um pouco mais sobre isso em:

- [Melhor tipo de dados para trabalhar com dinheiro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5746/melhor-tipo-de-dados-para-trabalhar-com-dinheiro/5760#5760)
- [Que tipo de dados (double, float ou decimal) eu deveria usar para representar moeda em .NET com C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11340/18246)

Comment: Muito obrigada pela indicações de leitura e pela resposta!